# Angular code not working without ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular

I have a component for logging in to a system that looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class LoginComponent extends OtherLoginComponent implements OnInit{

    loginWithPass = !(<RandomService>this.randomService).variable1;
    lText = !(<RandomService>this.randomService).variable1 ? 'LOG IN' : 'LOG IN 123';

    ngOnInit() {
        if(location.href.startsWith(environment.variable_url)){
            (<RandomService>this.randomService)._variable2 = true;
            this.lText = 'LOG IN 123';
        }
        this.loginWithCredentials = !(<RandomService>this.randomService).variable1;
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {

    }

    userPass() {
        this.loginWithPass = true;
        (<RandomService>this.randomService)._variable2 = false;
        this.lText = 'LOG IN';
    }
}
```

The above all works but when I remove the empty ngOnDestroy() I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? And what I should include in my ngOnDestroy so it is not empty?

Comment: can you show us how is RandomService being implemented or called?
also would be good to see the login.component.html

Comment: it looks like the OtherLoginComponent  has ngOnDestroy method with unsubscribe. So by adding empty ngOnDestroy to LoginComponent  you overide it.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you forgot to add OnDestroy after the implement OnInit ... Angular uses reflection and sees if you have implemented OnDestroy before calling it. Usually you put unsubscribe call in the NgOndestroy, you clean the view data that is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks! With my above code though I don't have anything to unsubscribe to - it seems strange having it empty